# Date of the week in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have table in MySQL which contain data like,

```
Week No.  Month   Year
   1      April   2016
   4      April   2016
```

I need to find date of Monday for the particular week.

Comment: Do you have dates table?

Comment: How do you define "week no"?

Comment: Please tell us what you have alreadu tried and what is not working

Comment: No dont have dates table. The data i got only contain that much information along with the total sales.
Trying to search slimier thing and didnt find anything

Comment: If this table is only the reference then you can not find date of a day without adding your own logic. closely matching Mysql function is DAYOFWEEK(date) but this is not what you are looking for. Therefore I think you should keep a reference of date or day itself in this table to get desired value from this table.

Comment: Thx Amar, created dates table and go the result... Thx everyone

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick, maybe you should have to adjust type of y parameter.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `calc_date`(y TEXT, m TEXT, w INT)
 RETURNS date
BEGIN
  DECLARE d DATE;
  SET d = DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(y,'-'),m),'-01'), '%Y-%M-%d'), INTERVAL w week);
  RETURN DATE_SUB(d, INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK(d) + 5)%7 DAY);
end;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

then you just have to call

```
select calc_date(`Year`,`Month`,`Week No.`) from yourtable;
```